# Linux - MySQL Master/Slave cluster - upgrade 8.0.17 to 8.0.25

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I'm running a cluster of MySql, 1 master, 1 slave (manage by an external app) on Linux and I would like to upgrade to the latest version in the same release without downtime.

8.0.17 to 8.0.25

According to the doc, I should :

1. Upgrade the slave first (Yum update) and restore the cluster
2. Restore the cluster and wait until the slave has catch up the master
3. Failover and disconnect the previous master
4. Upgrade the second member and restore the cluster

But in the doc, it is also stated that there could be an incompatibility between these versions due to some changes.
Could you someone help me to known if the replication should work after the slave upgrade ?
If I restore the cluster with master running 8.0.17 and the slave running 8.0.25, did the replication is going to work ?

I'm not sure, some say that this should works without any issues, some say that it's going to put the slave in read only mode, I'm a bit lost since I'm not an experienced DBA

Thank you for your help !

Comment: "Cluster" is ambiguous.  Are you using "Galera"?  Or "InnoDB Cluster"?  Or simply "Replication"?